# Why does the modulus operator behave differently in Perl and PHP?

Tags: php, perl, operators, modulus

I've this PHP function which does not work for negative numbers:

```
function isOdd($num) 
{
   return $num % 2 == 1; 
}
```

but it works for positive number.

I have this Perl routine which does the exact same thing and works for negative number also

```
sub isOdd()
{
  my ($num) = @_;
  return $num % 2 == 1;
}
```

Did I make any mistake in translating the function ? or is it PHP bug ?

Comment: "does not work" is not an explanation

Comment: I means to say it gives wrong results

Comment: @user640527: and why haven't you just looked what `$num % 2` returns before compare it with 1?

Comment: my idea was to use abs(). function isOdd($num) { return abs($num) % 2 == 1; }

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In PHP the sign of the result of `x % y` is the sign of **dividend** which is `x` but
 
in Perl it is the sign of the **divisor** which is `y`.

So in PHP the result of `$num % 2` can be be either `1`, `-1` or `0`.

So fix your function compare the result with `0`:

```
function isOdd($num) { 
  return $num % 2 != 0; 
}
```

Comment: but why? this is fundamental math. Why it changes ?

Comment: @user640527: Its a language design decision. Of the languages I know Perl and Ruby return sign of divisor and C,C++,Java and PHP return sign of dividend.

Comment: +1 (associated documentation) http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php : "The result of the modulus operator % has the same sign as the dividend — that is, the result of $a % $b will have the same sign as $a."

Comment: Python works like Perl and Ruby in this regard.  `5 % 2` and `-5 % 2` both return `1`, while `5 % -2` and `-5 % -2` both return `-1`.  **WATCH:** `perl -e '@langs = ( "perl -le ", "ruby -le ", "python -c"); for $dividend ("+5", "-5") {for $divisor ("+2", "-2") {for $lang (@langs) { $cmd = "$lang \047print $dividend % $divisor\047"; print "$cmd\t=> "; system $cmd} print "\n"}}'`